# Convert multi-dimensional array key value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, key-value

I have array like:-

```
$x = array(
  'a' => array('aa' => array('aaa' => array(1, 2, 3))),
  'b' => array('bb' => array('bbb' => array(1, 2, 3))),
);
```

Then, I want to modifying array to:-

```
$y = array(
  1 => array('a', 'b'),
  2 => array('aa', 'bb'),
  3 => array('aaa', 'bbb'),
);
```

Please help me!

NB: if the last array 2,1,3 will be `2->a,b; 1->aa,bb; 3->aaa,bbb`

Comment: I don't understand the link between input and output... why is `1` associated with `a` and `b` and `2` associated with `aa` and `bb`?
`1` and `2` are values at the end of the chain of all three keys, after all. Does it have something to do with the number of characters (`1` for 1 character, `2` for 2 characters, etc) or the index of the key you want to associate (`1` with `a` because it comes first, `2` with `aa` because it comes second) or something else entirely I cannot even guess??

Comment: try yourself, you will get the idea either possible or not.

Comment: there are will be group by dimentional. then last dimentional array to be key 1 -> a, b; 2-> aa,bb; 3->aaa.bbb @NadiaCerezo

Comment: Did you try anything??

Comment: What do you mean by "group by dimentional"??
If the input is `'aaa' => array('a' => array('aa' => array(2, 1, 3)))` how would it change your output?

Comment: i get question in the class PHP Language. I think this have answer. but I dont understand -_-. I not yet try anything. I don't know

Comment: like output what I want like that @NadiaCerezo

Comment: if like that will be `2->aaa; 1->a; 3->aa` @NadiaCerezo

Comment: Will your input arrays always have the same depth?

Comment: yes.. thank @NadiaCerezo

Comment: @Stfvns  the solutions given below will not work with increasing depth.thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$x = array(
  'a' => array('aa' => array('aaa' => array(1, 2, 3))),
  'b' => array('bb' => array('bbb' => array(1, 2, 3))),
);

$loop=true;
$item=array();


foreach ($x as $index => $value) {
if(!is_int($index)) $item[strlen($index)][]=$index;
while($loop){
    foreach ($value as $sub_index => $sub_value) {
        if (is_array($sub_value)) {
            if(!is_int($sub_index)) $item[strlen($sub_index)][]=$sub_index;
            $value=$sub_value;

        }
        else {
            if(!is_int($sub_index))$item[strlen($sub_index)][]=$sub_index;
            $loop=false;
        }
    }
}
    $loop=true;
}
var_dump($item);
```

### output

```
array(3) { 
   [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "a" [1]=> string(1) "b" } 
   [2]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "aa" [1]=> string(2) "bb" } 
   [3]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "aaa" [1]=> string(3) "bbb" } 
}
```

Comment: Well it was not me who downvoted you, just so you know (since you kindly informed me the other way around). ;)

Comment: Thank you  :)  personally I downvote (rarely) only if I have a justification and i post it, downvote without explanation are bad :D

Comment: I agree, but they also seem to be very common. :(

Answer (score 1):

You could try the approach in the code below. And by the way, you could [Quick-Test it Here](https://eval.in/650077).

```
<?php


    $x = array(
        'a' => array('aa' => array('aaa' => array(1, 2, 3))),
        'b' => array('bb' => array('bbb' => array(1, 2, 3))),
    );

    $result     = array();
    $result[]   = array_keys($x);
    $tmp1       = [];
    $tmp2       = [];


    foreach($x as $k=>$arrData){
        if(is_array($arrData)){
            foreach($arrData as $k1=>$v1){
                $tmp1[] = $k1;
                if(is_array($v1)){
                    foreach($v1 as $k2=>$v2){
                        $tmp2[] = $k2;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $result[]   = $tmp1;
    $result[]   = $tmp2;

    var_dump($result);

    //YIELDS:::

    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'a' (length=1)
          1 => string 'b' (length=1)
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'aa' (length=2)
          1 => string 'bb' (length=2)
      2 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'aaa' (length=3)
          1 => string 'bbb' (length=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you explained, I would suggest something like this:-

```
$x = array(
  'a' => array('aa' => array('aaa' => array(1, 2, 3))),
  'b' => array('bb' => array('bbb' => array(1, 2, 3))),
);

$y = array();
$l = array();
foreach ($x as $l[0] => $x2) {
    foreach ($x2 as $l[1] => $x3) {
        foreach ($x3 as $l[2] => $keys) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
                if (isset($y[$keys[$i]])) {
                    $y[$keys[$i]][] = $l[$i];
                } else {
                    $y[$keys[$i]] = array($l[$i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But please note that this code will fail if the depth changes or does not match the number of values that become keys...

Comment: the depth not will be change. but the number values maybe change like 2,1,3. It will the number of the index `2->aaa; 1->a; 3->aa`. And the boot last array number definitely same @NadiaCerezo

Comment: My solution does not assume that the number values are ordered. Please try it and tell me if it fails (and how it fails).

Comment: thank I think I will use this answer to my question. @NadiaCerezo

Comment: I didn't downvoted but I dont agree because you are here supposing that the array depth is alway 3 and the last array length is alway 3.

Comment: Indeed, @Amani, because those were assumptions that the author confirmed in the comments.

Comment: @Anant I know that solutions less brittle than mine are possible (there are ALWAYS other and often way better solutions)... But you should suggest to the author to look at your solution, not to me. I never pretended I was doing anything but treating the case where the depth is 3.
Also, I do not understand why you all insist that you did not downvote me... You can do it guys. I won't hold it against you, promise. ;)

Comment: I am just telling for knowledge sake.Thanks

Comment: Hi again I really didnt downvoted you contrairly I upvoted yestardy your anwer beacause it was not fair having a minus for a correct anwser but If you are the one who is dowvoting all my previous answers today (a 2 years ago answers/questions !)..then I have to tell you this is not ok I am not gonna react by downvoting you back but this is not mature sorry.